# Blender Stack Exchange Dark Theme

Tags: discussion

The site is too bright when working in a dark room or at evening when switching from all the 3D software that all has dark UI. Is there a Dark Theme?

*If you have your own feel free to post it next to mine to form a database*

Answer (score 10):

I decided to share mine. You get it through [userstyles.org here](https://userstyles.org/styles/163575/blender-stack-exchange-dark-theme). Give it some time to get used to.

[image]

If there are bugs pls comment below, I am sure there are places of the site I never visited so there might be weirdness. Also I hope it works in most browsers the same.

The style also hides the *New contributor* messages, if you want them comment this section of the theme:

```
/* New contributor, code of condunt */
   .new-contributor-indicator
   {
       display: none;
   }
```

If you want to do anything with the theme feel free, it's CC0.

[Edit] There is update for the new design with left-bar navigation, but for some reason does not auto-update (at least for me), uninstall-install of the theme solves that.

Comment: For anyone not already aware, the stylish addon promoted on userstyles.org now comes with telemetry/tracking components. You may want to use [stylus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/styl-us/), a fork with those parts removed, instead.

Comment: Nice catch @gandalf3, I didn't even know the Stylish addon existed. For Chrome the right stuff is here: [stylus for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne).

Comment: Thanks Jerryno! I like this a lot. It may not be obvious, so I'll mention: after installing **Stylus** the install button works on the userstyles.org page. Disregard that the logo in the upper left is for **Stylish** - it is compatible with both.

Comment: This increased readability by an order of magnitude.

Comment: The blender stackexchange seem to have change these days: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITwIo.png

Comment: @L0Lock Looking at it now also, I was away during weekend but will update it soon. Also I noticed the theme does not auto update very well when I make changes.

Comment: @L0Lock It's updated:)

Comment: awesome !
It could add one more suggestion, the "nex privilege" progression bar also needs some work: https://i.imgur.com/3HiW5BG.png And also this part: https://i.imgur.com/NVlVbgp.png

Comment: @L0Lock Good catch, thx. Fixed.

Comment: one last thing I guess, link in answers (and maybe comments) are a bit hard to see: https://i.imgur.com/z7mb3Tv.png

Comment: @L0Lock Try the update from yesterday, I am tweaking small things here and there as I bump into them. When I do an edit to the theme, the site tells it takes about 5 mins to update, but sometimes it does not update automatically. Sometimes it even does not update when hitting the update icon in theme manager and says it's up to date, when it isn't. And only after I uninstall and install again I can see the change. Weird.

Comment: I installed your dark theme again today, and it seems the SVG images that were hosted on `svgshare.com` have all gone down. I've patched the CSS for myself to get rid of the big red error images that appear in their place, but you might consider adding any relevant SVG images [inline in the CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10768631) instead. Cheers.